# MySQL default value as query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know this is against normalization rules, but how can I (if it is possible) set default value for column as a query, eg.:

```
ALTER TABLE Data
ALTER Sum SET DEFAULT SELECT Total*0.15 FROM Data;
```

Comment: I guess it is something that triggers can cover.

Comment: Its not Default constraint you should be looking at, it is computed column what you need.

Comment: To clarify the above, a trigger will detect when a new row is entered, and automatically calculate the information based on what was entered and enter the new row.   However, if you a thinking of "default" as something conditional (for example only what gets entered if nothing else is entered by, say, the user), then you might want to take a different approach and handle it in an application layer.

Comment: No, I just want simply calculate one value from another. Probably @sitilge answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming to trigger on `UPDATE`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_data
AFTER UPDATE ON Data
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE Data
SET NEW.Sum = (SELECT OLD.Total * 0.15)
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```